How to Implement a Guest Login in Django REST Framework
I currently have a backend setup where users can register by providing an email, name, and password. These fields are required for registration. I want to implement a guest login feature where a guest account is deleted when the browser is closed or the guest logs out.
How should I proceed to create a guest account, and what information should I include for the guest account (email, name, password)?
Here is the current code:
models.py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Manager for user"""

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create, save and return a new user."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address.')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), name=name, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        """Create and save a new superuser with given details"""
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Database model for users in the system"""
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_guest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar_color = models.CharField(max_length=7)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.avatar_color = random.choice([
                '#FF5733', '#C70039', '#900C3F', '#581845',
                '#8E44AD', '#1F618D', '#008000', '#A52A2A', '#000080'
            ])
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the user object."""

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'phone_number', 'avatar_color']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'required': False},
            'password': {'required': False, 'write_only': True, 'style': {'input_type': 'password'}, 'min_length': 6},
            'name': {'required': False},
            'phone_number': {'required': False},
            'avatar_color': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a user with encrypted password."""
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Update and return user."""
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return user


class GuestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for guests."""

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'name', 'is_guest', 'avatar_color']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'required': False},
            'name': {'required': False},
            'is_guest': {'default': True},
            'avatar_color': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Create and return a guest user with default values.
        validated_data['email'] = f'guest_{random.randint(100000, 999999)}@example.com'
        validated_data['name'] = 'Guest'
        validated_data['is_guest'] = True
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)


class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializer for the user auth token."""
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False,
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """Validate and authenticate the user."""
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')
        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'),
            username=email,
            password=password,
        )
        if not user:
            msg = _('Unable to authenticate with provided credentials.')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs

views.py
class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """Create a new user in the system."""
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.UpdateOwnProfile]
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'email',)


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """List all users."""
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]


class CreateGuestView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """Create a new guest."""
    serializer_class = GuestSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = serializer.save()
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        print('TOKEN: ', token.key)
        return Response({'token': token}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


class GuestLogoutView(APIView):
    """Logout a guest and delete."""
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_guest:
            request.user.auth_token.delete()
            request.user.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Create a new auth token for user."""
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES


class UserLoginApiView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Handle creating user authentication tokens"""
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES


class LogoutView(APIView):
    """Logout the authenticated user."""
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class ManageUserView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """Manage the authenticated user."""
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_object(self):
        """Retrieve and return the authenticated user."""
        return self.request.user

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.CreateUserView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('register/guest/', views.CreateGuestView.as_view(), name='register_guest'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('logout/guest', views.GuestLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout_guest'),
    path('token/', views.CreateTokenView.as_view(), name='token'),
    path('me/', views.ManageUserView.as_view(), name='me'),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]


You can do so on logout but how will you implement it on browser close?

My question is how can I implement the guest account?

Nothing stops it from being an ordinary user account which on logout, request.user.delete() is invoked. As for browser close, that will be a far cry.

If I create a guest account, which email and password should I use? To create the guest account, you just need to click on the “Guest Login” button.

Let “Guest Login” route to another URL. That endpoint will be used to authenticate a guest and another will be used to logout a guest. If it can be simple, don’t complicate it. Add a boolean attribute to the user model to differentiate guests from native users. Django already does that with admin, super admin and ordinary users. If you need more details, I’ll write up an answer.

@ChukwujiobiCanon it will be helpful, if you provide more details and write an answer.

I just got off from work now. Please share the AUTH_USER_MODEL you are currently using so that I will work off that.

I've added the code in the first post

1. Add a new attribute to your AUTH_USER_MODEL to recognize guests:
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Database model for users in the system"""
    •••Rest of code•••
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_guest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    •••Rest of code•••
2. Have a different View specifically to have guests:
 class CreateGuestView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """Create a new guest."""
    serializer_class = GuestSerializer
    •••Rest of code•••
3. Create the GuestSerializer used above:
class GuestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for guests."""
    •••Rest of code•••
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a user with is_guest."""
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(is_guest = True, **validated_data)
    •••Rest of code•••
4. Delete a guest on logout:
class GuestLogoutView(APIView):
    """Logout a guest and delete."""
    •••Rest of code•••
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
        request.user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
Remember to register all these new Views to a URL. An assumption made was that settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is correctly setup. One good reason for making this assumption is your use of get_user_model().

I tried to implement the guest login according to your instructions. The problem is, I want to send the token to the frontend, but I only get the newly created guest user but not the token, even though I return the token in the CreateGuestView. In the perform_create method I print out the token and it is valid. I included the current code in my initial post. Can you see why that is?

perform_create() should not return a Response. Even if it does, that return value is usually ignored. What you really want to do is override the create() method.
